# fread removes a different previously assigned character string

Tags: c

I'm reading in a binary file using fread, but in the process of this operation, another character string is changed into (null). Below is the part of the code that seems to cause the problem. The entire code is much longer, and my suspicion is that I'm running into problems with the available stack memory, but I don't know how to verify that.

```
char *foo;
foo   = argv[1];
double *array;

array= malloc(npts*sizeof(double));      //npts - number of points

FILE *fo = fopen(ofile, "r");
printf("String: %s\n",foo);
fread(&array,8,npts,fo);
printf("String: %s\n",foo);
```

The first occurence of the print statement returns the previously assigned value 'bar', but the second returns '(null)'.

I expected both of the print statements to return 'bar'.

Comment: While it's very likely that the `&array` expression is the culprit, there's really not enough to definitely say since you don't show a proper [mcve], or tell us your input or contents of the file, or why you read the file as binary when you opened it in text mode, or if there's any error checking (both `fopen` and `fread` can fail, as can `malloc`), of if you have checked `argc` to make sure `argv[1]` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&array` in `fread(&array,8,npts,fo);` is wrong; that is the address of the pointer. You should pass the pointer: `fread(array,8,npts,fo);`.

Comment: Hi Eric, that solved the problem! So using the address of the pointer only works when you read single values? Is that correct?

Comment: @Comos With `&array` you get a pointer *to the variable* `array`. It's a pointer to the pointer, of type `double **`.

Comment: And I guess writing npts*8 bytes over the pointer basically ruins all previous pointers, practically scrambling the entire code...